# How to add cypress code coverage for angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, package, cypress

My current angaular app uses Angular 6.1 and I want to cypress code coverage. All the examples I found are using Angular 8.x. As you know upgrading from Angular 6 to Angular 8 is not recommended and it might break many things. Has anyone successfully added cypress code coverage to Angular 6. Any help or suggestion on this will greatly help me.

Thanks in advance.

Now I will tell what I have tried

I am using this blog as reference [blog ref](https://dev.to/cssoldiervoif/code-coverage-with-cypress-angular-45pb?signin=true) and app [App github](https://github.com/GettinDatFoShow/ang-cy-cov-example) . I have cloned the app from above link. App is already in Angular 8 and I have downgraded to Angular 6. But when I try to build the app, I see this error

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['cypress']" should have required property 'class'.
```

I have given package.json dependencies and devdependencies as reference

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.8.8",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@briebug/cypress-schematic": "^3.2.0",
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "^1.14.0",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "4.1.3",
    "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cypress": "4.1.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "istanbul-lib-coverage": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^9.0.6",
    "nyc": "^15.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "ts-loader": "6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
```

My overall goal is to generate code coverage using cypress. If anyone has already generated code coverage for angular 6, please do let me know.

Comment: code coverage for what ? unit tests ? e2e tests ?

Comment: May not be possible, the error indicates a Schematics problem. The app you use uses `@briebug/cypress-schematic` which at earliest release has angular dependencies labelled v7.

Comment: Thanks @RichardMatsen ,can you tell me how you found it has earliest release has v7 dependencies, to be frank I am new in finding dependencies.

Comment: Hi @RachidO, yes I am trying to generate coverage for end to end test

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@briebug/cypress-schematic/v/1.0.0 earliest release was 2 years ago and how to find which angular version it is dependent

Comment: From the npmjs link, go to the github repository - on that page open the 'Switch branch or tags' dropdown. There's only one branch, but look in tags and scoot down all the way to v1.02 and select that release. Take a look in package.json, dependencies section and you can see the Angular dependencies have v7.

Comment: Having also looked through the code for `@briebug/cypress-schematic`, I'm not sure that it's doing anything related to instrumenting the Angular source (which is step 1 for code coverage). You may be able to extract it from the app and move forward.

Comment: I just noticed you have other Angular-related dependencies above that won't be compatible with Angular 6. Expect a cascade of errors from those (presuming they are even called).

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to give you a definitive answer, but is the approach I would try.

From the [Cypress docs page](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage.html#Examples),

> **Examples**
>
> - [skylock/cypress-angular-coverage-example](https://github.com/skylock/cypress-angular-coverage-example) shows an Angular 8 + TypeScript application with instrumentation done using **ngx-build-plus**.

From [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus)

> **Get the right version**
>
> Angular 6-7/ CLI 6-7: ngx-build-plus@^7
> Angular 8/ CLI 8: ngx-build-plus^8.0.0
> Angular 9/ CLI 9: ngx-build-plus^9.0.0

Switching to ngx-build-plus@7.7.2, you have a bunch of instructions under [Getting Started](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus/tree/7.7.2#getting-started) that look useful.

Once you have the app instrumented (see [Instrument your application](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage#instrument-your-application) on how to check), it should be plain sailing as @cypress/code-coverage works pretty well, even combines e2e, unit test and server (api) coverage.

Comment: Thank you so much Richard, will give it a try and let you know soon :)